# how to make html anchor accessible in asp.net mvc web application?

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

If i use a anchor tag in my asp.net mvc 2 web app how can i make sure the user can 'tab' to it in case he is just using his keyboard?

I use something like this but it is not accessible?

```
 <a id="someanchor">Upload statement</a>

   $("#someanchor").click(function () {
            //some js
        });
```

how to create an anchor tag that is accesible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an href - without one, the anchor is considered to be a non-interactive placeholder.

```
<a id="someanchor" href="javascript:void(0)">Upload statement</a>
```

In this case, the href is present, so the A ends up being a tabbable link and can be activated via keyboard, but the target URL - javascript:void(0) - is basically a no-op, so no actual navigation occurs.